# boundingRect in Path doesn't output anything in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, bounds

I was trying to create a function for `Path` that divides the frame in half.

```
extension Path {
    mutating func divideInHalf() {
        move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: boundingRect.midY))
        addLine(to: CGPoint(x: boundingRect.maxX, y: boundingRect.midY))
    }
}
```

However, this seemed to do nothing. In fact, I tried experimenting with `boundingRect` but it refused to output anything at all.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "waiting for value..."
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)  // This stays as "waiting for value..."
            Path { path in
                path.divideInHalf()
                text = "\(path.boundingRect.height)"  // This does nothing
            }
            .stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

I thought maybe it had something to do with using the inout variable so I tried doing this as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "waiting for value..."
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)  // This stays as "waiting for value..."
            Path { path in
                path.divideInHalf()
                let rect = Path { path in 
                    path.move(to: .zero)
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
                }.boundingRect  // Getting the value from the instance directly

                text = "\(rect.height)"  // This still does nothing
            }
            .stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding more lines to the path but that still did nothing. Does anyone know how `boundingRect` works? Why is it not outputting anything, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What is the `boundingRect` of an empty `Path`?

```
print(Path { _ in }.boundingRect)
/// (inf, inf, 0.0, 0.0)
```

In `divideInHalf`, your calls to `move` and `addLine` are passing `midY` and `maxX`, which are both `CGFloat.inf` (infinity). `Path` appears to ignore such calls.

If you put some content in your `Path`, `divideInHalf` will add a subpath. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Path { path in
                path.addEllipse(in: .init(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
                path.divideInHalf()
            }
            .stroke()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .border(.red)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

The horizontal line through the circle is the result of `divideInHalf`:

[image: circle with a horizontal line through it]

Note that you might like the result better if you change the `move` call in `divideInHalf` to use `boundingRect.minX` instead of `0`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. If this is the case why did `boundingRect` still return nothing in the final code snippet (when I try accessing `boundingRect` using `rect`)? I added content in the Path but it still returned nothing.

Comment: You have to add content to the path before calling `divideInHalf`.